# What does "Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException" mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, javabeans

I keep getting this error and I have no idea where to even start. I am very new to spring and did not code any of the project. I am simply trying to run it, but cannot get it to work.

Here is the full error:

```
Jul 31, 2015 11:37:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericFormDBEntityManager' defined in class path resource [com/subaru/snet/forms/config/GenericFormsDBConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [genericFormPersistenceUnit] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property eclipselink.logging.level has an illegal value test.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I just want to know what this means and what threads I can look at to find a solution because I've been searching all day and cannot find an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Look for a file named `peristence.xml`. If exists, it should have a property named `eclipselink.logging.level`. Change it's  from `test` to `INFO`

Comment: @orid YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER!!!! THANK YOU!!

Comment: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property eclipselink.logging.level has an illegal value `test`.**

Answer (score 0):

`org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException`

It happens when a new entity is not in `persistence.xml`.

> Internal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property eclipselink.logging.level has an illegal value test.

As you can see from above, your `eclipselink.logging.level` has an illegal value.

So you need to change it to a valid value.

The following are the valid values you can use.

[image]